# how to keep image vertical on side bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making the clone of just dial for practice but i got stuck in sidebar.
It is showing horizontal image instead of vertical on sidebar. Please tell me the
solution so i can proceed.

image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLgx7.png)

HTML CODE

```
<aside class="side-border" id="side-border-right">
        <div class="right-side"><img src="images/j1.png"</div>
   </aside>
```

CSS CODE

```
.side-border {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #9ca0a6;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 24px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 171px;
    z-index: 40;
}

.side-border>div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 12px;
    left: 24px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.side-border>div.right-side {
    left: auto;
    right: 34px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100% 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the image with the text "Free Listing" ? or the bus image?

Comment: I am talking about free listing

Comment: From your css, you are transforming the parent element, not the image. Can you add a class to the image, and then from CSS put something like  transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: @joraid...it is working..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use this css in `.right-side` element. You don't need to use style in the parent element. Although you can use these styles in image also. Look here...

```css
.right-side {position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 50%; transform-origin: 100% 0% 0; transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50%);}
```

```html
<div class="right-side"><img src="http://www.cutetravelmate.com/images/priority_shinet1.gif"</div>
```